# Postgresql date/time field value out of range

Tags: postgresql

Hey guys so I'm trying to COPY command some csv files into my database and the error that I get is:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1596080481467"
```

I've tried changing the datestyles already to different ones and it's not really working. Anyone know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: Show some rows from the  `CSV` file, and shared the `COPY` command too

Comment: This is happening because `1596080481467` is a time in microseconds and that cannot go directly into a `timestamp` field. You will need to load this CSV into a table that does not have a `timestamp` field and then do the conversion e.g. `select to_timestamp(1596080481467/1000); 2020-07-29 20:41:21-07`